# Kivy Filechooser overlapping text on scroll with screens

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

#### Versions

- Python: 3.7
- OS: Windows 10
- Kivy: 1.11.1
- Kivy installation method: pip

#### Description

FileChooser overlaps text on scrolling through files list. Looks like the 1st content stays and on scroll the content of scrolled data is getting displayed on top of 1st content.

#### Code and Logs

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, BoundedNumericProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

class FirstWindow(Screen):
    def show_load(self):
        content = LoadDialog(load=self.load, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Load file", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def cancel(self):
        pass

    def load(path, selection):
        print(path, selection)

class LoadDialog(FloatLayout):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)

class EditorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("editor.kv")
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        screen = FirstWindow(name="first")
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)
        self.screen_manager.current = "first"

        return self.screen_manager

if __name__ == "__main__":
    editor_app = EditorApp()
    editor_app.run()
```

**KV File**

```
<FirstWindow>:
  BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Button:
      text: "Select Folder"
      on_release: root.show_load()

<LoadDialog>:
  BoxLayout:
    size: root.size
    pos: root.pos
    orientation: "vertical"
    FileChooserListView:
      id: filechooser

    BoxLayout:
      size_hint_y: None
      height: 30
      Button:
        text: "Cancel"
        on_release: root.cancel()

      Button:
        text: "Load"
        on_release: root.load(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)
```

**Screenshots**
[image]

Comment: the same problem any update?

Comment: @SalihKaragoz Please check https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6742

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who are facing the same issue, I resolved by replacing FileChooser with Plyer's native filechooser. Disussion on Github can be [found here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6742)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line

```
kv = Builder.load_file("editor.kv")
```

your code will work fine